# Best way to interact with a service for exploitation purpose

Tags: python, bash, security, sockets, netcat

Suppose I have a service to interact with. Using netcat it would be something like this:

```
> nc 127.0.0.1 8080
hello
hi how are you?
```

I want to automatize the interaction with this service in order to perform some attack e.g. format string. So I create a Python script and that was really painful to make it work. Here's the code:

```
    t = Telnet(HOST, PORT)
    t.write('2\n')
    for _ in xrange(10)): print(t.read_some())
    t.write('3\n')
    for _ in xrange(12)): print(t.read_some())
```

The problem here is the response from the service. The behavior I was expecting from this script was the following:

1. Send request for example "hello"
2. Get the response: "hi how are you?"

In this case the service is quite simple but suppose I have a service that prints a menu of options or a welcome screen, I had to read all this stuff and manually find the response to the command I sent (using the for _ in xrange ...).

To summarize: what's the best way to interact with such service by taking into account ONLY the response of an input command?

*I don't know if python is right for this things. I tried using sockets but it was even worse than telnet because of the function recv*

Comment: Have you checked out `socket.makefile()`? It allows you to read lines from a socket like you would with a file (`for line in sock.makefile():`)

Comment: But it looks like the problem remains. I would have to check the file  and manually skip lines to find the response of the command I sent.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), which "talks" to interactive programs with the help of a user provided script.

**Usage**

```
expect ./interact
```

or making `interact` executable (`chmod a+x interact`):

```
./interact
```

where `interact` is the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn nc 127.0.0.1 8080
send -- "hallo\r"
expect "hi how are you?\r"
```

This is just a simple example, the man page is full of in depth explanations and there are also example scripts which come with the installation.

**References**
 * http://linuxaria.com/howto/2-practical-examples-of-expect-on-the-linux-cli?lang=en

Comment: Looks promising. Is it possible to integrate this with python? Like take the response and use it in a python script?