# How to open a bash/ssh session in shell script and run commands in the remote session?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I try to do the following in a shell script:

```
bash;
```

in the bash context:

- run `./a.out`

And In `./a.out` context I need to simulate keystorkes:

```
yes
3292
no
```

How can I do it? All my tries failed since `&`, `&&` and `;` executes the subsequent command in the main shell context and not in the bash.

```
bash && echo "yes" > /dev/console
```

I have seen [use expect in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174813/use-expect-in-shell-script) aren't there any alternative using native shell commands ? I don't want to be dependent on other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), which "talks" to interactive programs with the help of a user provided script.

**Usage**

```
expect ./interact
```

or making `interact` executable (`chmod a+x interact`):

```
./interact
```

where `interact` is the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./a.out
send -- "yes\r"
expect "3292\r"
send -- "no\r"
```

This is just a simple example, the man page is full of in depth explanations and there are also example scripts which come with the installation.

**References**

- http://linuxaria.com/howto/2-practical-examples-of-expect-on-the-linux-cli?lang=en
- [Best way to interact with a service for exploitation purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980336/best-way-to-interact-with-a-service-for-exploitation-purpose/16980604#16980604)